# Is there a way in pyqtgraph to set a level of e.g. a FillBetweenItem?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

In my application i have a lot of different FillBetweenItems from different types and I don't want to remove eacht time and plot all Items again. I'd like to use curve1.setData() and curve2.setData(). For each class I'd like to set a level: E.g. FillBetweenItem of class1 should always be on top of FillBetweenItem of class2. While Class3 will always underneath class2. Is there something I am missing?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

class RedClass:
    def __init__(self, ax = None):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lowerCurve = None
        self.upperCurve = None
        self.fillItem = None
    def draw(self, ax = None):
        pen = pg.mkPen(None)
        if self.lowerCurve is None:
            self.lowerCurve = self.ax.plot([1,2],[1,1], pen = pen)
        else:
            self.lowerCurve.setData(x = [1,2], y =  [1,1])
        if self.upperCurve is None:
            self.upperCurve = self.ax.plot([1,2],[3,3], pen = pen)
        else:
            self.upperCurve.setData(x = [1,2],y =  [3,3])
        if self.fillItem is None:

            self.fillItem = pg.FillBetweenItem(self.lowerCurve, self.upperCurve, brush = pg.mkBrush('r'))
            self.ax.addItem(self.fillItem)
class GreenClass:
    def __init__(self, ax = None):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lowerCurve = None
        self.upperCurve = None
        self.fillItem = None
    def draw(self):
        pen = pg.mkPen(None)
        if self.lowerCurve is None:
            self.lowerCurve = self.ax.plot([1.5,2.5],[1.5,1.5], pen = pen)
        else:
            self.lowerCurve.setData(x =[1.5,2.5], y =  [1.5,1.5])
        if self.upperCurve is None:
            self.upperCurve = self.ax.plot([1.5,2.5],[2.5,2.5], pen = pen)
        else:
            self.upperCurve.setData(x = [1.5,2.5],y = [2.5,2.5])
        if self.fillItem is None:
            self.fillItem = pg.FillBetweenItem(self.lowerCurve, self.upperCurve, brush = pg.mkBrush('g'))
            self.ax.addItem(self.fillItem)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    ax = pg.PlotWidget()
    greenOne = GreenClass(ax = ax)
    redOne = RedClass(ax = ax)
    #time of draw call determines which class is plotted on top
    redOne.draw()
    greenOne.draw()
    ax.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It depends if I call redOne.draw() first or greenOne.draw() first what color will be shown on top:

[image]

Is there a way to set e.g. level that Fillbetween items of the redclass are always on top of green ones? Or do I have to take care of every single item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the ZValue: an item with a higher ZValue will always be in front of an item with a lower ZValue:

```
# ...
redOne.draw()
greenOne.draw()

greenOne.fillItem.setZValue(0)
redOne.fillItem.setZValue(1)

ax.show()
# ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot! Is there any performance issue if I choose higher range of z Values? Do you know it maybe?

Comment: @Sebus No, it can even take floating values as the docs point out:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setZValue

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Also for the docs link. I've been there yesterday, but didn't see it :D